# Anonymous methods not omitting parameters anymore?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have been workig on a report on delegates for some time now in addition to working with them for over a year.

Looking up some info on the differences between anonymous methods used in C# 2.0 and lambda expressions in C# i read something about a functionality that 2.0 anonymous methods provide which lambda's dont: they can omit the parameter list.

After doing some research on this i try testing this out on my personal IDE which is running the latest version of C#, finding out that when i try to assign an anonymous method without any parameters to my Delegate type using them i get an error:

Delegate Test.MyHelloDelegate does not take 0 arguments

```
class TestClass
{
        public delegate void MyHelloDelegate (string s);
        MyHelloDelegate Hello = delegate () { Console.WriteLine("Hello from delegate"); };

        private void CallHello ()
        {
            Hello("dummy");
        }
}
```

My own assumption would be that it got patched out since people will only use lambda's anyway but i do need some evidence for that since i will be putting it in my report. Would love to know if someone has any idea what is going on with this.

Comment: Nothing has changed. You are simply not using the parameter-less syntax. Change to `delegate { Console.WriteLine("Hello from delegate"); }` to see the behavior you're asking about. Your difficulty is based on a trivial typographical (syntax) error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cause your attached anonymous method doesn't takes an input parameter. Change it to

```
public delegate void MyHelloDelegate (string s);
MyHelloDelegate Hello = delegate(string s) { Console.WriteLine("Hello from delegate " + s); };
```

If you don't want pass any parameter then consider using the syntax below

```
MyHelloDelegate Hello = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Hello from delegate "); };
```

Comment: I know this. But if you look at the documentation it says i can ignore the parameter and not give any input. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods -> Line 4 and https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/c/10097-deep-c-anonymous-methods-lambdas-and-closures.html?start=1 -> example 7

Comment: Looks like i found the awnser to my Question @Rahul. It was a matter of syntax. Looks like this my second source used the wrong syntax. Thanks alot!